# Programatically created UIPageControl not showing

Tags: swift, autolayout, uipagecontrol

In my view hierarchy, I have a UIPageViewController (inside a container view). Underneath that is the UIPageControl and at the bottom is a stack view consisting of a text view and a button. I see the UIPageViewController and the stack view but not the UIPageControl. Any idea what I am doing wrong:

```
// Page view controller
        introPageViewC = IntroPageViewC()
        addChild(introPageViewC)

        introPageViewC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(introPageViewC.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            introPageViewC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            introPageViewC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            introPageViewC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            introPageViewC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        introPageViewC.didMove(toParent: self)

        // Page view control

        introPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.orange
        introPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

        view.addSubview(introPageControl)

        introPageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        introPageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        introPageControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        // Stack view
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 30

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: introPageControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
```

Expected output:
[image]

**Edit:**
Attempt at adding to the stack view:

```
var allViews = [UIView]()

        // Adding to stackview
        introPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.orange
        introPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        allViews.append(introPageControl)

        nameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 40))
        nameTextField.placeholder = "Mealplan name"
        Utilities.styleTextField(nameTextField)
        nameTextField.setPadding()
        allViews.append(nameTextField)

        let nextButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        nextButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 40)
        nextButton.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
        nextButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
        nextButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "NexaBold", size: 16)
        Utilities.styleDefaultButton(nextButton)
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapSubmit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        allViews.append(nextButton)

        errorLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 40)
        errorLabel.font = UIFont(name: "NexaBold", size: 16)
        errorLabel.textColor = .systemRed
        errorLabel.textAlignment = .center
        errorLabel.alpha = 0
        allViews.append(errorLabel)

        for eachView in allViews {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(eachView)
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible you just aren't seeing it because it's white dots on a white background? Give your page control a background color and see if it shows up. If still not, use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect your layout.

Answer (score 0):

`introPageControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true`
I believe you meant `centerXAnchor`?

Comment: I changed it to Y when I was playing around with it but I did change it back to X and it was the same result. The page control is still invisible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the topAnchor all wrong. Right now, it seems to be constrained to the bottom of the containerView plus 10, which is *just off the screen*. I think you meant to say **-10**.

```
introPageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Comment: The containerView contains the UIPageViewController so it's bottom is just above the UIPageControl. It's not view for the entire screen if that is what you mean.

Comment: Oh okay. Are they both in the stackview?  You don't have to worry about their Y positioning if they are. Mind sharing that code?

Comment: No, only the textView and button are in the stackview. But to get the PageControl to appear I tried to put it in the stackview and it still will not show up. I have added the code for the stackview in the Edit section above.

Comment: and removed this `stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: introPageControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true` as well?

Comment: Mmm how is your UIPageControl `init`-ed? and does the rest of the stack view look fine?

Comment: I have simply done this: var introPageControl = UIPageControl()